# If $x$ is a solution to $ax\equiv b \pmod m$ then so is $x+m/d$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose $\gcd(a,m)=d$
.If $x$ is a solution to $ax\equiv b \pmod m$ then so is $x+m/d$
I'm unsure how this is done but this is my attempt:

Suppose $\gcd(a,m)=d$

Now suppose $x$ is a solution to $ax\equiv b \pmod m.$

Then there are solutions to $ax+mz=b$ for some $z\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Then we have 
$$ax + \frac{am}d - \frac{am}d+ mz = b \\ a(x+\frac{m}d) + m (z-\frac{a}{d}) = b \\ a(x+\frac{m}d) + m(\ell) = b \qquad \text{for some $\ell:=z-\frac{a}{d}\in\mathbb{Z}$} \qquad ( \text{since d|a})
$$
So 
$$a(x+\frac{m}d) \equiv b \pmod m
$$
Is this the correct way to go? Is there a better way to prove this? I feel like I didn't use the condition $gcd(a,m)=d$ I simply used that $d|a$.

Comment: It is correct, in fact you use also $d\mid m$ so that $x+\frac md$ is an integer too, so we use $d$ is a common divisor of $a,m$, but I don't think we need to know it is actually the gcd. Another remark, just say $ax\equiv b\pmod m\iff \exists z\in\mathbb Z$ s.t. $ax=b+mz$, this is somewhat simpler wording than saying $ax+mz=b$ has solutions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather more simply
$$a\left(x+\frac md\right)=ax+\frac adm\equiv b\pmod m$$
as $ax\equiv b\pmod m$ and $a/d$ is an integer (since $d$ is a divisor
of $a$).